# Example of ROS2 C++ blocking action request

Tags: ros, ros2, action

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm looking for a C++ example of a blocking action request. Basically I seek the C++ version of this Python answer:  https://answers.ros.org/question/377269/a-less-asyncronous-way-of-using-ros2-action-clients/?answer=377584#post-id-377584

In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
my_action_client_->async_send_goal(my_request, send_goal_options);

// block until complete here
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393461/example-of-ros2-c++-blocking-action-request/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2021-12-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-28**:
Hi @AndyZe, here you can find the C++ version of the Fibonnaci example shown in the previous answer. https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/foxy/action_tutorials/action_tutorials_cpp/src  Hope that's what you are looking for

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2021-12-28**:
Yep, thanks. It doesn't block until the action finishes, though.

```
    this->client_ptr_->async_send_goal(goal_msg, send_goal_options);
  }
```

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2021-12-28**:
I suspect the answer is to use `async_get_result()` but the syntax is a little tricky. I wish there were an example.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-28**:
There is a little bit of information in the [source code](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/ef41059a751702274667e2164182c062b47c453d/rclcpp_action/include/rclcpp_action/client.hpp#L399-L401)

```
/// Asynchronously get the result for an active goal.
  /**
   * \throws exceptions::UnknownGoalHandleError If the goal unknown or already reached a terminal
   *   state.
   * \param[in] goal_handle The goal handle for which to get the result.
   * \param[in] result_callback Optional callback that is called when the result is received.
   * \return A future that is set to the goal result when the goal is finished.
   */
  std::shared_future<WrappedResult>
  async_get_result(
    typename GoalHandle::SharedPtr goal_handle,
    ResultCallback result_callback = nullptr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
  auto goal_handle = my_action_client_->async_send_goal(request, send_goal_options);

  auto result = my_action_client_->async_get_result(goal_handle.get());

  if (result.get().code == rclcpp_action::ResultCode::SUCCEEDED)
  {
    return true;
  }
```

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2021-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0